# Unable to load strapi instance in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, strapi

I am trying to run test cases for strapi but it is not allowing me to do so. I am using postgres database.

**I have checked other answers and I have only one database.js file and not database.json**

The error I get-

lerna ERR! yarn run test:local stderr:
●  process.exit called with "1"

```
   7 | async function setupStrapi() {
   8 |   if (!instance) {
>  9 |     instance = await Strapi().load();
     |                ^
  10 |     await instance.app
  11 |       .use(instance.router.routes()) // populate KOA routes
  12 |       .use(instance.router.allowedMethods()); // populate KOA methods

  at Strapi.stop (../../node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:316:13)
  at Strapi.stopWithError (../../node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:302:17)
  at ../../node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/mount-models.js:688:18
  at module.exports (../../node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/mount-models.js:708:7)
  at mountConnection (../../node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/index.js:84:7)
      at async Promise.all (index 0)
  at Object.initialize (../../node_modules/strapi-database/lib/connector-registry.js:30:9)
  at DatabaseManager.initialize (../../node_modules/strapi-database/lib/database-manager.js:43:5)
  at Strapi.load (../../node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:362:5)
  at setupStrapi (tests/helpers/setup.js:9:16)
```

error Command failed with exit code 1.

Any leads to fix this?